# Keep results of last run of the day only

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to make a script that every time I press the button refreshes my investment value and then posts the date and the investment value on another sheet.

I managed the following code.

```vb
Sub Refresh()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date
    Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("B3").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

If I hit the button more than once, I just want to keep the last entry of the day.

My idea was to solve it with an `if else`, but it ignores the `if`:

```vb
Sub Refresh()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value Then
        Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("B3").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date
        Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("B3").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean if you hit the button twice, you only want to keep the last entry?

Comment: Yes I just want to keep the last entry of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update Worksheet

- If you don't have a button or another control to run `Refresh` on the `ActiveSheet`, I would strongly suggest you define it like `Protfolio` is defined.
- If the code is in the `ActiveWorkbook`, you should definitely use
  `ThisWorkbook` instead, which refers to the workbook containing this
  code.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Refresh()
    
    ' Define workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' Do.
    wb.RefreshAll
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet ('tgt').
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Define Old Date Cell ('cel').
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = tgt.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    
    ' Check if Old Date Cell does not contain today's date.
    If cel.Value <> Date Then
    ' Does not contain today's date:
        ' Define New Date Cell ('cel'), the cell below Old Date Cell.
        Set cel = cel.Offset(1, 0)
        ' Write today's date to New Date Cell.
        cel.Value = Date
    Else
    ' Does contain today's date:
        ' Do nothing because Old Date Cell is becoming New Date Cell.
    End If
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet ('src').
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("Portfolio")
    
    ' Write value from Source Cell to Target Cell.
    ' (Source Cell is next to New Date Cell).
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = src.Range("B3").Value

End Sub
```